# Azure Self signed certificate

Tags: azure, x509certificate, self-signed

"Can I" and "How to" use a self-signed certificate on the staging deploy of my cloud service?

Is there specials configurations necessary? i've checked a couple tutorials but they only mention https... and i don't to use HTTPS... i want to programmatically load a self-signed certificate...

i do can load the certificate... but i get the yellow screen of death saying "The X.509 certificate CN=mysite.com is not in the trusted people store."... how can i revert this using a self-signed certificate?!?!

i'm loading the certificate this way:
`X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumb, false);`

EDIT: The certificate is here to make WS-Federation authentication possible...

Comment: How are you loading the certificate? `X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile`?

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the certificate is? You are saying it's not for SSL traffic, so what's it used for? Please elaborate. And by all means, show us the code you are using to load the cert.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson no... the certificate is "installed" on the azure portal...